# tvOS button with text label underneath

Tags: xcode, uibutton, tvos

I'm trying to make native tvOS buttons like in Apple's Movies app, where the button is an icon (say, a plus sign) with a text label underneath (say, "Wish List"). I had assumed this would be a supported UIButton style on tvOS, esp as the tvOS HIG, under the Interface Elements | Buttons sections, states:-

> If appropriate, show descriptive text beneath an icon button. An icon
>   should generally be sufficient for conveying meaning. However, if
>   additional text provides useful information or context, put it below
>   the button.

Anyone know if this is possible without building a custom control?

Answer (score 2):

Got confirmation from an Apple staff member on the forums that they don't support this.

So a custom control it is...